# Удаление элементов массива текущего iter

Tags: rust

**Вопрос:** Как правильно удалять элементы `Vec` массива, в текущем `iter`?

**Неправильный код:**

```
//all_kernel - Vec массив, элементов

let mut del:Vec<usize> = Vec::new(); //хранение индексов которые требуется удалить
let mut n = 0; //текущий индекс
for a in all_kernel.iter(){
    if a.is_active() {
        del.push(n);
        n += 1;
        continue;
    }
    if a.is_hidden() {
        del.push(n);
        n += 1;
        continue;
    }
    n += 1;
}
for i in del.iter(){
    println!("DEL {}", &i);
    all_kernel.remove(*i);
}
```

**Проблема:** приходится делать два `for` цикла + массив удаленных индексов чтобы удалить элементы `all_kernel` массива. Также элементы массива смещаются при удалении что делает этот код не рабочим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть в стандартной библиотеки такая функция: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain . Она делает то что вам нужно и делает это эффективней.

Хочу обратить внимание, что на самом деле эта функция делает на самом деле обратную вещь, т.е. оставляет все элементы, для которых предикат возвращает `true`. Но ничего не мешает использовать эту функцию для удаления определённых элементов.

Comment: Тоже неплохо. ...